# Unable to get information from SQL Server

Tags: android, sql-server

Configuration:  SQlserver 2014 . SQL Server Browser - Running. Firewall - Disabled

```
String URL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.2.22/spin;instance=SQLEXPRESS";
String USER = "XXXX";
String PASS = "XXXX";
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
```

This one works in java client, but not in Andorid application I have received this error "Unable to get information from SQL Server"

```
11-08 10:35:07.011 5684-5698/zkc.com.nfcread W/System.err: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to get information from SQL Server: 172.16.4.10.
11-08 10:35:07.012 5684-5698/zkc.com.nfcread W/System.err:     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.MSSqlServerInfo.<init>(Unknown Source)
11-08 10:35:07.015 5684-5698/zkc.com.nfcread W/System.err:     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(Unknown Source)
11-08 10:35:07.015 5684-5698/zkc.com.nfcread W/System.err:     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Unknown Source)
11-08 10:35:07.015 5684-5698/zkc.com.nfcread W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:175)
11-08 10:35:07.015 5684-5698/zkc.com.nfcread W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:209)
```

Comment: What research and debugging efforts have been tried?

Comment: Silly mistake . Adding permission resolve this problem (android.permission.INTERNET).